# while launching Presto CLI it is showing permission denied error

Tags: presto

While launching Presto CLI it is throwing permission denide error. 
I used to launch PrestoCLI by using the following command,

Presto$ /home/reddy/presto/presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog hive --schema default

Before launching PrestoCLI, I Install Presto and Discovery Service.

Can anyone assist me on this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more info. Can you provide stack? configuration of nodes ? (node.config)

Answer (score 1):

Per the [installation instructions for the CLI](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/cli.html), it needs to be made executable by running `chmod +x`, just like any other UNIX executable.

Answer (score -2):

Try running it as administrator like this:

```
su <yourpassword>
./presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog hive --schema default
```